# Application Insights does not send dependencies entries

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I've started using Application Insights to track my application events in client environment.

When I'm running application from Visual Studio, Insights show me a lot of logs with `dependency`, which tells me about calls to external resources, but I can't see them in Application Insights Analysis portal. Other events (like custom events) are working fine.

Am I missing some configuration? I was searching through `TelemetryClient` and `TelemetryConfiguration` objects to find any property for setting that but I couldn't find any.

Could please guide me to enable that?

Answer (score 0):

What version of .net are you running?  when development, you might be on 4.6 locally, but when deployed on .net 4.5?  On .net 4.5 you'd need status monitor on the server to get dependency collection.

According to this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net-dependencies/

> If your web app runs on .NET 4.6 or later, you can either install the
>   Application Insights SDK in your app, or install Application Insights
>   Status Monitor. You don't need both.